# Damage from D.VA's Mech

Tags: overwatch

With the changes to D.VA in the most recent patch, I've been noticing some strange things (or perhaps I'm imagining it, hence my question). This is from the perspective of another character, in my case, Symmetra.

Does D.VA's mechsuit damage you when it loses all health, and D.VA ejects out?

How much damage does D.VA's mechsuit do when she calls in a new one? Is there a difference in damage between being on the ground when hit, or in the air?

Comment: D.va is *vulnerable* while her mech is being called, but it doesn't cause damage on its own, no. I'm also pretty certain that you won't take damage just by virtue of ejecting, but obviously you're being shot at the time you're ejecting, so do keep that bit in mind.

Comment: Clarification added in an edit. I'm talking about a player other than D.VA.

Comment: Oh, that makes way more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D.Va's mech suit being destroyed does no damage to surrounding enemies- it is merely removed from the game and control is transferred to the z-suit Hana pilot.

When she summons a new mech, it deals 50 damage to anyone caught in the path of the mech. There does not appear to be any fall-off or splash damage, it is merely a 50 damage hit.

This is something I can come back to with evidence when not at work if necessary.

Comment: Is there a difference in damage between my character being grounded or in the air when D.VA calls in a new mech?

Comment: None that I'm aware of- I'll get some footage together of a grounded and airborne pharah getting hit by the mech summon. But as far as I've experienced, there's no damage difference.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf So I did some testing- You get a flat 50 damage if your hitbox collides with the new mech hitbox, or are within the pink circle while on the ground. The mech hitbox starts above her, at about ice wall height, any higher and the mech is only a visual aid, not an object.